# Advanced datatables JS library for custom software with grouping similar to Airtable

Tags: open-source, javascript, data-visualization, user-interface

I see that when sharing tables with Airtable you get fancy colorful frontend things like filtering, grouping and sorting.

For example I create a table and when I share it, the user looking at it can do this grouping out of the box in zero minutes.

[image: Airtable Sample]

Unfortunately this is for Airtable tables only.

I have multiple data tables in a MySQL and we have multiple panels to view data made with PHP, but it gives only basic filtering and sorting done with basic javascript.

I am looking for a modern datatable JS library, not depending on JQuery, able to do those fancy things out of the box.

## Question

What open-source JS libraries can do this cool stuff to be used in custom-coded web-apps out of the box?

### Purpose

In my own software, provide similar fancy filtering/grouping/sorting than airtable does.

### Objective requirements

- Javascript library
- Open sourced
- Not-dependant on jQuery
- Installable via yarn (we use symfony for the back and we use encore to build the front)
- Alive (recent commits, not dead, community)